# VFP macro expansion in USE statement

Tags: macros, visual-foxpro

A table is being opened in a folder whose name is being provided by the user.

```
lFolder = Getfile()
lFilename = lFolder + “mytable.dbf”
USE &lFilename IN  0 ALIAS  . . .
```

This usually works fine.  However, if the folder whose name is supplied by the user has an embedded space, so ‘My folder’, the USE instruction fails.  But this instruction works successfully :

```
USE (lFilename) IN 0 . . .
```

Are there any rules which say when one should use the Ampersand (&)  construct and when one should use the bracket construct?  And is this only applicable to the USE statement?

Thanks.  Andrew

Comment: Don't ever use & when () will do. http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Articles/Handling%20Code%20that%20Changes%20at%20Runtime.pdf

Comment: Thank you Tamar,  Very helpful, and your article explicitly refers to embedded spaces, which appeared to be the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to write that code is:

```
local lFolder, lFilename
lFolder = Getdir()
lFilename = addbs(m.lFolder) + 'mytable.dbf'

* or a single GetFile() to select the dbf directly

USE (m.lFilename) IN  0 ALIAS  . . .
```

There are more than one point in this code:
1) Declare your variables as local. Without that declaration, it would work and VFP would implicitly declare them as private. It is a good practice to declare local and also would help with intellisense, if you use tools like ISX.

2) Using addbs() ensures a backslash. It is just coding safe.

3) Use m. (aka mdot) for memory variables. Using mdot, you are telling VFP explicitly that it is a memory variable. Using mdot there is no harm, but if you don't you might get into hard to catch bugs (and also in tight loops, it is proven to be much faster using mdot).

4) Finally, your original question. A Filename is a "name" so do not use a macro expansion (&) operator but "name expression" anywhere there is a Name. A "name expression" is simply a set of parentheses. If something is a "name", then use "name expression" (a fieldName, fileName, folderName, variableName ...).

Apart from rules, unfortunately many VFP developers abuse the & and use it too often. In reality, probably it has too few places where using makes sense and that is SQL clauses. Not something like:

```
lcSQL = "select * from ..." + ... + "..."
&lcSQL
```

(which often you may see this pattern as well) but this one where parts of SQL use macro expansion. ie:

```
select &fieldList ;
from (m.tableName) ;
where &lcWhere ;
order by &lcOrder
```

Note that m.tableName is a "name" and thus used with "name expression". FieldList variable might be holding a single fieldName or a series of fieldNames (ie: "CustomerId" or "CustomerId, CompanyName, ContactName") and cannot be used as a "name expression", needs to be macro expanded.

Comment: Thanks Cetin

1.  The variables lFolder, lFilename were declared as local.  Local variables begin with an ‘l’ or even ‘lc’.  The declarations were not shown in the code fragment, but are there.

2.  Under VFP9, afaik, GETDIR() returns a string with a terminating ‘\’ (if it returns a directory);  please correct me if I am wrong!  Your ADDBS() call does no harm;  but I have not included it.

3.  Advice about the use of m. – noted.  As you say, it might be useful in a tight loop.

4.  Thanks for this.  Will take your advice and use a name expression here.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Andrew_46 -- if you appreciate Cetin's long and thoughtful answer, it would be good if you upticked him.

Comment: Yes, it was a long answer, and I am sure it was well meant.  Thanks again Cetin. In fact Tamar's comment includes a very helpful link which explains this subject in great detail.